# sort: How to specify the order in which multiple sorts are performed

Tags: sorting

In the following example, there are two criteria for sorting -- orders with an *inactive* status should appear last in the last, and all orders should be organized by order number from smallest to largest.  The problem with the current approach is that the orders with an *inactive* status are not being sorted by their order numbers.  How can a user programmatically specify the order in which sorts are performed?  E.g., first sort by status, and then sort everything by number; or, first sort everything by number, and then sort by status without altering the initial sort.

```lisp
(let ((seq '((5996635507 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635504 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635414 (((rank . child) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635416 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635415 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635413 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635115 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc ."misc")))))
      (inactive-list '("REJECTED" "CANCELED" "REPLACED" "FILLED" "EXPIRED")))
  (sort seq (lambda (a b)
              (let* ((order-number-a (car a))
                     (order-number-b (car b))
                     (alist-a (caadr a))
                     (alist-b (caadr b))
                     (status-a (cdr (assq 'status alist-a)))
                     (status-b (cdr (assq 'status alist-b))))
                (and (< order-number-a order-number-b)
                     (not (member status-a inactive-list)))))))
```

**CURRENT RESULT**:  Order `5996635507` is *before* order `5996635115`.

```
((5996635413 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635414 (((rank . child) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635415 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635416 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635504 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635507 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635115 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc . "misc"))))
```

**DESIRED RESULT**:  Order `5996635507` is *after* order `5996635115`.

```
((5996635413 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635414 (((rank . child) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635415 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635416 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635504 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635115 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc . "misc")))
 (5996635507 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc . "misc"))))
```

---

**SECOND ATTEMPT**:

```lisp
(let ((seq '((5996635507 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635504 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635414 (((rank . child) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635416 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635415 (((rank . grandchild) (status . "AWAITING_PARENT_ORDER")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635413 (((rank . parent) (status . "PENDING_ACTIVATION")) (misc ."misc")))
             (5996635115 (((rank . parent) (status . "CANCELED")) (misc ."misc")))))
      (inactive-list '("REJECTED" "CANCELED" "REPLACED" "FILLED" "EXPIRED")))
  (sort seq (lambda (a b)
              (let* ((order-number-a (car a))
                     (order-number-b (car b))
                     (alist-a (caadr a))
                     (alist-b (caadr b))
                     (status-a (cdr (assq 'status alist-a)))
                     (status-b (cdr (assq 'status alist-b))))
                (cond
                  ((and (not (member status-a inactive-list))
                        (not (member status-b inactive-list)))
                        (< order-number-a order-number-b))
                  ((and (member status-a inactive-list)
                        (member status-b inactive-list))
                        (< order-number-a order-number-b))
                  ((and (member status-a inactive-list)
                        (not (member status-b inactive-list)))
                    nil)
                  ((and (not (member status-a inactive-list))
                        (member status-b inactive-list))
                    t))))))
```

Comment: I would do two sorts, the first by order number, the second by active status (making sure that at least the second is a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)). Alternatively, split it into active and inactive bunches, sort each one by order number and concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate function just needs to return non-nil if the first element should sort before the second.

> E.g., first sort by status, and then sort everything by number

- if A.status < B.status, return non-nil
- if A.status > B.status, return nil
- if A.status = B.status, test the number and return based on *that*.

The logic is entirely up to you.

> The problem with the current approach is that the orders with an inactive status are not being sorted by their order numbers

You are returning `nil` whenever A is 'inactive', regardless of other criteria.

Comment: Thank you ... I updated the question with a second try, but it doesn't look right ... although the end result seems to be correct.  The third test test condition looks like it should be non-nil; and, the fourth test condition looks like it should be nil -- but if I change those around to what seems to make sense, then the list looks inverted.  I wasn't able to use a `defvar` to create a reusable test sequence because `sort` is destructive, so I just let-bound the entire sequence for the new test.

Comment: All those double-negatives in your comparison code... that could be *much* cleaner.  I suggest you bind `active-a` and `active-b` variables, and maybe make the values integers so you can just compare them numerically.

Comment: "The third test test condition looks like it should be non-nil" -- The 3rd condition is `(and (member status-a inactive-list) (not (member status-b inactive-list)))` which is "A inactive; B active"; so if you want active items to appear *before* inactive items the correct return value is `nil`.  When your own code is so confusing that you can't see the logic, it's time to refactor for readability.